# KinematicBody2D stutters/moves back and forth

Tags: 2d, physics, movement, godot-3, kinematic

I'm working in Godot 3.5, and trying to set up a navigation polygon for my kinematic body to mode around inside, but when I try to send it to some point, the body 'stutters'/moves back and forth in the same place.

This my code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D


onready var nav_agent := $NavigationAgent2D
onready var path := $Path

var path_q : Array = []

var direction 
var velocity
func _ready():
    nav_agent.set_target_location(position)
    path.set_as_toplevel(true)
    
func _physics_process(delta):

    if not _arrived_to_location():
        direction =  position.direction_to(nav_agent.get_next_location())
        velocity = direction * 250
        move_and_slide(velocity)
    elif nav_agent.is_target_reached() and not path_q.empty():
        nav_agent.set_target_location(path_q[0])
        path_q.remove(0)
    else:
        path.clear_points()

func move_to(coord:Vector2):
    if path_q.empty():
        path.points = [position]

    path.add_point(coord)
    path_q.append(coord)

func _arrived_to_location():
    return nav_agent.is_target_reached() and path_q.empty()
```

`path` is just to visualize where the body is supposed to go. `path_q` is a queue of points where the body has to go in that order.

[image: Debugging screenshot]

Since this is just an image, you can't see some stuff. `UnitToken.position` and `UnitToken.direction` values go crazy, they always are changing but not enough to make `UnitToken` move beyond that point, so that's where the stutter comes from, but `nav_agent.get_next_location()` is always the same point.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Are you not overshooting your target?

You have this code:

```
direction =  position.direction_to(nav_agent.get_next_location())
velocity = direction * 250
move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Here (assuming no obstacles) the body would move `velocity * delta`, which might or might not be more than the distance to the target.

This is the distance to the target:

```
var distance := position.distance_to(nav_agent.get_next_location())
```

And thus, the maximum speed would be (remember that speed is distance over time):

```
var max_speed := distance / delta
```

Then you can limit the length of `velocity` to that:

```
direction =  position.direction_to(nav_agent.get_next_location())
var distance := position.distance_to(nav_agent.get_next_location())
var max_speed := distance / delta 
velocity = direction * min(250, max_speed)
move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Which, by the way, is the same as this:

```
var displacement := nav_agent.get_next_location() - position
var distance := displacement.length()
var max_speed := distance / delta

direction =  displacement.normalized()
velocity = direction * min(250, max_speed)
move_and_slide(velocity)
```